# If "prime" means first, what are second, third and so forth?

Tags: countable-nouns

Title covers it all really.
If "prime" means first, what are the correct terms for second, third and so forth?

Comment: Secondary, tertiary... ? Is that what you mean? Please be more explicit, clearly the title **doesn't** cover it all. There are lots of definitions of "prime".

Comment: I wasn't aware of there being multiple definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a Latin-derived equivalent to first. We didn't take anything else, so they're normally used with the other ordinals.

Prime, second, third...

Primary, secondary, tertiary...

It lets "first" be defined mostly in the ordinal sense, while "prime" usually means first in prestige and importance.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context.

In finance, "prime" loans are "first-choice", in that banks expect nearly all of the borrowers to make their payments on time.  "Sub-prime" loans are worse.

In painting, the "primer" is the first coat.  It is designed to adhere to most clean surfaces, and to be a good surface to paint on; but it is not designed to retain its color, nor is it designed to withstand sunlight.  The "top-coat" is an actual coat of paint, which is designed to adhere to "primer", be a particular color, and withstand sunlight.

In [meat grading](http://meat.tamu.edu/beefgrading/), "prime" meat has the most (fat) marbling, followed by "choice", "select", and "standard".

As Catija points out, "primary" is followed by "secondary", "tertiary", "quaternary", *et cetera*.

In arithmetic, "prime" numbers are positive integers that have exactly one factor greater than one.  "Composite" numbers are positive integers that have more than one factor greater than one.